# Google compute - SSH - port 22 blocked by ufw

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, ufw

Well, I was doing some server setup reading this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#securing-the-app) and ran the following commands -

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
sudo ufw enable

sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
```

This basically closed all other ports and now SSH is not working at all. From the browser or from osx terminal.

I have connected via serial login and can see ufw blocking connections -

```
[ 1292.322021] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=00.00.00.00 DST=10.142.0.2 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=45 ID=7906 PROTO=TCP SPT=58028 DPT=22 WINDOW=60720 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Is there any way to ssh now as I am unable to access the machine at all.

Comment: Use the console - online if it's a cloud host, or in person if it's physical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By Default, all ports are blocked other than port 22 to allow you to ssh to the VM instance. You also have the option to open port 80 and/or 443. You can see which ports are open by default by checking the Firewall rules within the Cloud Console. I am mentioning this to inform you that you do not need to install ufw in the future.

You will have to provide a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptlocalfile) to the VM instance to enable SSH. You can just create a simple bash script with either command listed below.

$ufw allow ssh

or

ufw allow 22

You do not have to use the sudo prefix since the startup script runs as root already.

Comment: Script thing worked like a charm. You saved my day. Many thanks Jason!

Comment: I have a same problem with Aseem, but I still didn't get your answer. I mean, I only access my instances from SSH, either from SSH putty and SSH from instances. So Can you explain more spesific where should I use the startup script for solve this issue? Do I have to create a new Instance or is there console to go into my server/instance ?? PLease help

Answer (score 5):

Just complimenting the accepted answer.

Some are asking how you can include a start-up script on a VM that you can't even SSH into. You can accomplish this by:

- Navigate to the GCP Console under your VM instance
- Stop your VM Instance
- Click Edit
- Under custom meta-data, add the key `startup-script` and the value:

  ```
   #! /bin/bash
   sudo ufw allow 22
  ```

  Hope this clears some of the confusion :)